# Cookies on a remote site with IE

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer, cookies

We’re generating a video and pushing it to our client's web site. You can see it here, as an example:

http://www.expresspassport.com/

We're calling the code by a remote JavaScript file that injects a few DOM elements. We're also setting a cookie to handle repeat visitors in a different behavior then new visitors. Up until a few weeks ago, all browsers were handling this correctly.  It looks like something has changed in the default IE settings and some users don't get the cookie now.
Has anyone heard changes that have happened recently that could have affected the behavior?  I've looked down several avenues, but I have run out of leads. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Jason

Comment: changes for IE? IE7 -> IE8. no more.

Comment: So you're saying it's specifically an IE 8 issue? Is there a workaround?  Our clients want this functionality.